# How can I convert from packets to bytes

Tags: c#, windows, ip

In .NET 4, I'm using `IPGlobalStatistics` class.

The properties `OutputPacketRequests`, `OutputPacketsDiscarded`, etc in this class are referred in packets.

How can I convert these properties into bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Packets can be of different sizes, so there's no single mapping from "number of packets" to "number of bytes". (That class *only* gives the numbers of packets - not the contents of the packets themselves.)